# How to run express.js 4.0 app in webstorm 7

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

As you might know that new express.js version has came out and it contains most of the changes including restful routes etc. In previous version to run an app we use to set app.js in webstorm but now in express 4.0 to run an app npm is required `npm start`  is command. 
Does any body know how to setup an express 4.0 app in webstrom to run from it?

Comment: I don't think that `express@4.x` requires `npm start` to work. Did you encounter any error you could share with us when running simply `node appname` ?

Comment: Hi m_vdbeek, thanks for head up. Actually when you use node appname nothing happens.No response from server.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose your issue without some kind of source code but check that your app listens on a port and also that you don't get `"EACCESS"` or `"EADDRINUSE"` errors.

Comment: m_vdbeek try to create express 4.0 app and try to run app with node app.js. I found one hack for this see my ans below.

Comment: for example, Heroku uses npm start, so it's better to use npm start in development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Configuration, go to "JavasScript file" and change it to this value: bin\www

Answer (score 0):

Click the 'Run' button (the green triangle), and in the console you should see: "Express server listening on port 3000".  Then you can access your app at `http://localhost:3000`.

Answer (score -2):

I found one hack for this. That is   when you create new express.js 4.0 app you will notice that appname/bin/www.txt file get created which contains following code

```
var debug = require('debug')('my-application');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

just comment out this line `var app = require('../app');` copy that code and paste at bottom of your app.js i.e appname/app.js 
that's it now you run an app from `node app.js`